# Attempted to read past end of the stream error in MySQL

Tags: .net, mysql, ioexception, connector

I'm running into a problem with MySQL where I have the following error.

```
MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset. ---> 
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> 
System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
```

This error occurs when I have this running overnight. And it happens infrequently, so it is hard to track down WHY it's happening. I am using .NET 3.5 with MySQLConnector 6.2.4.0.

I am running it using the following code.

```
        public DataSet Read(String query, List<KeyValuePair<String, object>> parameters)
    {
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = null;
        DataSet returnVal = null;
        if (query != null && query.Length > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                returnVal = new DataSet();
                if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Open();
                }
                query = SQLHelper.formatSQL(query);
                MySqlCommand command = buildCommand(connection, query, parameters);

                Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

                command.CommandTimeout = 120;
                adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
                log.Debug(adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText);
                stopwatch.Start();
                adapter.Fill(returnVal);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 150)
                {
                    log.Debug(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms to run query");
                }
                else
                {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, object> kvp in parameters)
                        {
                            sb.Append(kvp.Key);
                            sb.Append(" = ");
                            if (kvp.Value != null)
                            {
                                sb.Append(kvp.Value.ToString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.Append("NULL");
                            }
                            sb.Append(", ");
                        }
                    }
                    log.Warn(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms to run query: " + adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText + "Values: " + sb.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException msqlex)
            {
                log.Error(msqlex);
                returnVal = null;
                MessageBox.Show(query + "\r\n" + msqlex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error("Query is empty. Returning null");
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
```

As you can see, I am not manually attempting to read anything >< I'm doing an `adapter.fill(x)`, so I have no control over reading past the end of the stream.

Why may be this happening?

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it throws that when the timeout is exceeded. There is a bug fix about it NOT doing so, so if they fixed it, now it does.

[connector-net-en.a4.pdf (MySQL Documentation)](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-net-en.a4.pdf)

MySQL Connector/NET did not throw an EndOfStreamException exception when net_write_timeout was exceeded.
(Bug #53439)

Comment: Any idea what the solution to this is then?

Comment: Thanks! Timeout was the issue. Adding larger value to connection string helps. e.g. `....database=sample_db;ConnectionTimeout=600;DefaultCommandTimeout=600;`